# How to override saveAction backpack laravel admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am developing a custom behavior in `backpack-for-laravel` `V4` to upload files then user will be forwarded to a screen to match the content of file contents.

There will be two steps in this behavior so I need to change `save_action` first to upload and in the next screen it will be save header.

Please advice,

Comment: I managed to do that by editing `vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/SaveActions.php` I added the operation I want and the `saveAction` and it worked as expected on the operation I want, but I am searching for a better solution without the need to edit library files, because of this I kept this question open.

Answer (score 1):

Good news for you. There is a full PR to allow devs to manipulate saveActions.

[backpack dynamic save actions](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/2356)

I think it's going to be merged on 4.1 but you can manually add the code in your project if you need it ASAP.

Best,
Pedro